# Delete a row from a table if there is another row that has "BETTER" value

Tags: mysql, sql-update, delete-row

I could not quite frame a question that describes my problem right.

But.. this is what I am trying to achieve

There is a table that stores the results of students appearing for exams.

```
Student Name |Roll Number| Subject | Result

Andy         | 111       | Math    | Fail
Bob          | 112       | Science | Pass
Carl         | 113       | History | Pass
Andy         | 111       | Math    | Pass
Bob          | 112       | Science | Fail
Bob          | 112       | History | Fail
Carl         | 113       | History | Fail
```

The above being a MySQL table, I would want to delete specific rows that reflect a "bad" result if there is another row that has a "good" result for the same student+subject combination.
ie.. Andy has failed in Math the first time but passed later. So the first row should be deleted. But  also, Bob Passed science once, but failed in the second attempt. So the second attempt should be deleted.

The table I would want:

```
Student Name |Roll Number| Subject | Result

Bob          | 112       | Science | Pass
Carl         | 113       | History | Pass
Andy         | 111       | Math    | Pass
Bob          | 112       | History | Fail
Carl         | 112       | History | Fail
```

If deleting cannot work, maybe insert the best values into another table and truncate this one.

Comment: What is considered "bad" and what is considered "good"?

Comment: if it is a FAIL, it is bad. If it is a PASS, its good

Comment: Do you want to make a permanent modification to this table, or do you merely wish to affect the results returned in a query? So far, there's two answers, and they seem to have gone both ways.

Comment: I don't mind making a permanent modification too. Seems like both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data provided, you can do this as an aggregation query:

```
select StudentName, RollNumber, Subject,
       (case when MAX(Result = 'Pass') = 1 then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end) as Result
from t
group by StudentName, RollNumber, Subject
```

Comment: It still stores the value of the latest result.
Latest here refers to the value that occurs last in the table.

Comment: Ignore previous comment. My table was not formatted right. Worked fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql's special [multiple-table delete syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

```
delete a 
from results a
join results b
    on b.roll_number = a.roll_number
    and b.subject = a.subject
    and b.result = 'Pass'
where a.result = 'Fail'
```

This will only delete the fail rows if there's a matching pass row. If there are other "good" results than "pass", you will have to tune the conditions accordingly.